# Generate a JavaScript/JSON object from an Objective-C enum

Tags: javascript, objective-c, c, json, enums

I want to convert Objective-C enums to JavaScript objects that will be used in some JavaScript parts of my program.

glib-mkenums would do exactly what I need:

```
glib-mkenums --eprod "var @EnumName@ = {" --vprod "@VALUENAME@: @valuenum@," --vtail "};" TheEnum.h
```

except that it chokes on inline comments, and doesn't handle some Objective-C enum definitions. I considered preprocessing the files with `sed` before passing it to mkenums, but it seems mkenums also has problems when the result of a bitwise operation is used as a default value.

Are there alternatives to glib-mkenums?

I also made an attempt with Objective-C (not my native tongue...) and a macro:

```
#define TO_JS_PROP(x) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s: %d,", #x, x]
- (NSString *)theEnumToJavaScriptObject
{
    NSMutableArray *jsObj = [NSMutableArray new];
    [jsObj addObject:@"var TheEnum = {"];
    [jsObj addObject:TO_JS_PROP(TheEnumOne)];
    [jsObj addObject:TO_JS_PROP(TheEnumTwo)];
    [jsObj addObject:@"};"];
    return [jsObj componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
}
```

It works OK, but loses in maintainability and flexibility compared to a parser/preprocessor, which is a bit annoying when glib-mkenums was so close to being perfect.

Comment: I think you might be interested in [Convert ObjC enum constants to string names](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18088041) -- I wrote a little Python script that uses libclang, which is [up on GitHub](https://github.com/woolsweater/CocoaEnumToString).

Comment: I will have a look at CocoaEnumToString, but I would need to introduce this to other developers workflows, so I want something that's either included with the default OSX Developer tools (which python-clang does not seem to be), or something small enough that I can check it into our repository. Lots of requirements, sorry..